Apache ECharts how to include hovered series in tooltip with trigger axis?
I am rending a numeric line series with multiple boolean custom series on a x time axis. The boolean custom series is rendered in a way where it creates a horizontal swim lane for each boolean series and the opacity of the lane is determined by the value. Because tooltip trigger is axis, I can only see the boolean value at the time the data point exists (the beginning of the custom series rendered item). How can I include the boolean value for all boolean series in the tooltip no matter where I hover on the chart so that I can see the numeric value of the lines series as well as all the boolean series values that intersect with the hover position at a given point in time?
Apache ECharts custom example: link
Image of hovering a specific point in time in the Apache Echarts custom example linked above
Expectation: When I hover over a specific point in time I expect to see the numeric value from the line series as well as the boolean values from the custom series that intersect with the hover position at a given point in time. In the image I provided, I expect to see these values in the tooltip: 84.5, false, false.
What I have tried:

Adding tooltip rules custom series with trigger "item". This does not work as the numeric values are no longer included in the tooltip. I believe this happens because once a custom boolean series is hovered it takes precedence over other tooltip rules and displays only the value of the series being hovered.

What I have considered:

Using a stacked area step line series for the boolean data where false equates to 0 and true equates to 1. I believe this might cause some issues. First is that I would like to use these series for other types of data that will have more states than boolean. For example: true, false, null. In that case I will need multiple different visual representations of this state. I believe a stacked area step line series would only achieve 2 states. Shaded and not shaded. Second is that I won't have control over how the area is shaded when the data is false (equates to 0).


The easiest solution that came to my mind is to just add all the line points to the boolean data arrays. Since this gives intervals of multiple boolean values that are equal, I changed up your rendering function slightly to only render from the points where the boolean value changes.
Example:
const NUMBER_DATA = [
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:00:12.000Z'), 78.1],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:04:45.000Z'), 76.3],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:07:24.000Z'), 72.4],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:12:13.000Z'), 73.3],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:17:43.000Z'), 84.5],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:21:56.000Z'), 81.0],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:26:35.000Z'), 77.9],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:29:32.000Z'), 65.4],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:32:04.000Z'), 51.3],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:35:27.000Z'), 44.2],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:39:51.000Z'), 39.8]
];
const BOOLEAN_DATA1 = [
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:00:12.000Z'), true],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:11:13.000Z'), false],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:24:37.000Z'), true],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:30:11.000Z'), false],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:32:50.000Z'), true],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:39:51.000Z'), false]
];
const BOOLEAN_DATA2 = [
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:00:12.000Z'), false],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:07:52.000Z'), true],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:13:48.000Z'), false],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:20:11.000Z'), true],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:33:23.000Z'), false],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:39:51.000Z'), true]
];

function addPointsToBoolData(booldata) {
  let index = 0;
  for (let datapoint of NUMBER_DATA) {
    if (booldata[index] === undefined) {
      booldata.push([datapoint[0], booldata[-1][1]]);
      continue;
    }
    
    while (booldata[index][0] < datapoint[0]) {
      index++;
    }
    
    if (datapoint[0].getTime() === booldata[index][0].getTime()) {
      index++;
      continue;
    }
    
    if (index === 0) {
      booldata.splice(index, 0, [datapoint[0], booldata[index][1]]);
    } else {
      booldata.splice(index, 0, [datapoint[0], booldata[index-1][1]]);
    }
  }
}
addPointsToBoolData(BOOLEAN_DATA1)
addPointsToBoolData(BOOLEAN_DATA2)

function getRenderItem(categoryIndex, data) {
  return function renderItem(params, api) {
    const date = api.value(0);
    const val = api.value(1);

    if (params.dataIndex === data.length - 1) {
      return null;
    }

    if (data[params.dataIndex - 1] && data[params.dataIndex - 1][1] === val) {
      return null;
    }
    
    let index = 0;
    let nextVal = val;
    while (data[params.dataIndex + index + 1] && val === nextVal) {
      index++;
      nextVal = data[params.dataIndex + index][1];
    }
    
    const nextDate = data[params.dataIndex + index][0];

    const start = api.coord([date, categoryIndex]);
    const end = api.coord([nextDate, categoryIndex]);
    const height = api.size([0, 1])[1];

    const opacity = val ? 1 : 0.75;

    var rectShape = echarts.graphic.clipRectByRect(
      {
        x: start[0],
        y: start[1] - height / 2,
        width: end[0] - start[0],
        height: height
      },
      {
        x: params.coordSys.x,
        y: params.coordSys.y,
        width: params.coordSys.width,
        height: params.coordSys.height
      }
    );
    return (
      rectShape && {
        type: 'rect',
        transition: ['shape'],
        shape: rectShape,
        style: {
          fill: api.visual('color'),
          opacity
        }
      }
    );
  };
}
option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    valueFormatter: (value) => (typeof value === 'number' ? value : value[1]),
    axisPointer: {
      axis: 'x'
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'time'
  },
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value'
    },
    {
      type: 'category',
      show: false,
      data: ['Boolean Data 1', 'Boolean Data 2']
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      yAxisIndex: 0,
      data: NUMBER_DATA
    },
    {
      type: 'custom',
      yAxisIndex: 1,
      renderItem: getRenderItem(0, BOOLEAN_DATA1),
      data: BOOLEAN_DATA1
    },
    {
      type: 'custom',
      yAxisIndex: 1,
      renderItem: getRenderItem(1, BOOLEAN_DATA2),
      data: BOOLEAN_DATA2
    }
  ]
};


Another possibility would be to use a custom tooltip formatter function which only triggers on the line series and computes the boolean values inside. Note, that you lose the colored circle indicating the series.
Example:
const NUMBER_DATA = [
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:00:12.000Z'), 78.1],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:04:45.000Z'), 76.3],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:07:24.000Z'), 72.4],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:12:13.000Z'), 73.3],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:17:43.000Z'), 84.5],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:21:56.000Z'), 81.0],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:26:35.000Z'), 77.9],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:29:32.000Z'), 65.4],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:32:04.000Z'), 51.3],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:35:27.000Z'), 44.2],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:39:51.000Z'), 39.8]
];
const BOOLEAN_DATA1 = [
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:00:12.000Z'), true],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:11:13.000Z'), false],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:24:37.000Z'), true],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:30:11.000Z'), false],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:32:50.000Z'), true],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:39:51.000Z'), false]
];
const BOOLEAN_DATA2 = [
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:00:12.000Z'), false],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:07:52.000Z'), true],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:13:48.000Z'), false],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:20:11.000Z'), true],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:33:23.000Z'), false],
  [new Date('2024-06-13T00:39:51.000Z'), true]
];
const booldata = [BOOLEAN_DATA1, BOOLEAN_DATA2]

function getRenderItem(categoryIndex, data) {
  return function renderItem(params, api) {
    const date = api.value(0);
    const val = api.value(1);

    if (params.dataIndex === data.length - 1) {
      return null;
    }

    const nextDate = data[params.dataIndex + 1][0];

    const start = api.coord([date, categoryIndex]);
    const end = api.coord([nextDate, categoryIndex]);
    const height = api.size([0, 1])[1];

    const opacity = val ? 1 : 0.75;

    var rectShape = echarts.graphic.clipRectByRect(
      {
        x: start[0],
        y: start[1] - height / 2,
        width: end[0] - start[0],
        height: height
      },
      {
        x: params.coordSys.x,
        y: params.coordSys.y,
        width: params.coordSys.width,
        height: params.coordSys.height
      }
    );
    return (
      rectShape && {
        type: 'rect',
        transition: ['shape'],
        shape: rectShape,
        style: {
          fill: api.visual('color'),
          opacity
        }
      }
    );
  };
}
option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    valueFormatter: (value) => (typeof value === 'number' ? value : value[1]),
    axisPointer: {
      axis: 'x'
    },
    formatter: (params) => {
      const series = params[0];
      if (series.componentSubType !== 'line') return null;
      
      const time = series.axisValue;
      let tooltip = series.axisValueLabel + '<br> line series: ' + series.data[1] + '<br>';
      
      for (const boolNumber in booldata) {
        const dataArray = booldata[boolNumber];
        for (let index in dataArray) {
          if (dataArray[index][0] > time) {
            if (index === 0) {
              tooltip += 'custom series ' + boolNumber + ': ' + dataArray[index][1] + '<br>';
            } else {
              tooltip += 'custom series ' + boolNumber + ': ' + dataArray[index - 1][1] + '<br>';
            }
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      
      return tooltip;
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'time'
  },
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value'
    },
    {
      type: 'category',
      show: false,
      data: ['Boolean Data 1', 'Boolean Data 2']
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      yAxisIndex: 0,
      data: NUMBER_DATA
    },
    {
      type: 'custom',
      yAxisIndex: 1,
      renderItem: getRenderItem(0, BOOLEAN_DATA1),
      data: BOOLEAN_DATA1
    },
    {
      type: 'custom',
      yAxisIndex: 1,
      renderItem: getRenderItem(1, BOOLEAN_DATA2),
      data: BOOLEAN_DATA2
    }
  ]
};


Thank you, these are great solutions. I also appreciate the changes to the rendering function. I was thinking about ways to achieve combining equal boolean intervals and your solution achieves that elegantly. I was hoping for something more built in to the apache echarts configuration. But if that is not achievable I think these are still great solutions

Do you know where the types you are using for the formatter params are located? I am using typescript, and can not find type definitions or documentation for axisValue but they do seem to exists on params.

Sadly I dont know. I think there are some issues with typing in echarts. I just logged the params and chose what seemed appropraite. You could also just use the data property to compute the neccessary values.
